# When referring to the word "sensitive" what does having a greater sensitivity mean?

Tags: meaning

This might sound a bit confusing, so let me specify.

> John is more sensitive to food than Louise

Does this sentence mean John is able to taste more food, and therefor has a larger range of food, or only likes a specific kind of food, and therefor has a smaller range of food than Louise?

As another example:

> Instrument A is more sensitive to colour than instrument B

Again, similar question. Does instrument A accept more or less colours than instrument B?

Also, I'm not entirely sure what to tag this question, so feel free to tag it or suggest tags.

Comment: it means its reaction to the same stimulus is more extreme.

Comment: Have you looked it up in a dictionary?  If so, please refer to that and then explain what you still don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"John is more sensitive to food than Louise"

means:

"John is influenced by food more easily (quickly) than Louise is."

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sensitive?q=Sensitive%20) :

***sensitive***

adjective

(REACTING EASILY)

: easily influenced, changed, or damaged, especially by a physical activity or  effect.

As about instruments or devices

"***sensitive***"

[means](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/sensitive)

"able to sense very small changes in something.

For example:
a highly sensitive device / instrument;
sensitive scales."

Answer (score 1):

welcome to EL&U. The sentence means one of three things to me:

1) John has a more discerning palate than Louise and can distinguish more flavours

2) John knows more about food and as is, therefore, more discerning than Louise

3) John has more food *sensitivities* than Louise (that is more foods make him ill if he consumes them).

Sensitivities can be similar in effect to allergies but are caused by a different mechanism (see [this link](https://www.pomona.edu/administration/dining/health-wellness/allergies/sensitivities-vs-allergies) or search for "sensitivities vs allergies" for more information.)

As it has become more common both to recognise and to discuss food sensitivities in the last few decades I suspect that the third explanation is more likely but that could only be determined with more context.

As @Jim says in his comment "more sensitive" means having a more extreme reaction to the same stimulus (which is why one piece of equipment can be said to be *more sensitive* than another) but in a culinary context this can have the different meanings given above.